# Creating a non-alias CNAME with Cloudflare?

Tags: domain-name-system, cname-record, cloudflare

To verify my domain, someone at Google requested me to create a **CNAME** with this:

> Create the following CNAME record through your domain hosting provider:
>
> Label/Host: deleteGAPPSnotBefore20171127utc
>
> Destination/Target: case-XXXXX-for-example.com-at.google.com
>
> Time to live (TTL): 3600

After creating it, I got this reply:

> Unfortunately, we won´t be able to proceed with the process with the record reflecting as an alias. Please coordinate with your domain host and ask assistance in adding the provided record values as a CNAME record.
>
> As much as I would love to accept the record you created as a proof of your domain ownership, our security policy requires us that the values be reflected in the proper record type.

Now, the [definition itself](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CNAME_record) says that *CNAME is a type of record used to specify that a domain name is an alias for another domain*.

The question is, what are these people from Google expecting me to do? **How do I create a non-alias CNAME if a CNAME record is an alias by definition?** There's no drop down box to select the CNAME type in Coudflare (and I guess in any other DNS panel for the matter).

This makes no sense, but I can't reply this to the Google support guy as they'll always stand their ground.

Comment: What exactly did you enter as the CNAME record and what does the record resolve as using `nslookup` or `host`?

Comment: "*There's no drop down box to select the CNAME type in Coudflare*" I don't use Cloudfare but a quick search turned up the following: https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200169046-How-do-I-add-a-CNAME-record-  - You may also check that you haven't selected [CNAME flattening](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200169056-CNAME-Flattening-RFC-compliant-support-for-CNAME-at-the-root)

Comment: @SimonGreenwood I have entered case-XXXXX-for-example.com-at.google.com where XXX is the number of the support ticket. It resolves to the Cloudflare IP normally like all my other subdomains.

Comment: @HBruijn According to Cloudflare, they will only flatten the CNAME at the root of the domain. There's no option to disable flattening.

Comment: It shouldn't resolve to a Cloudflare IP. You need to disable caching (the orange cloud on the right hand side of the CNAME entry.

Comment: Thanks Simon, please add a reply and vote so I can accept your answer.